# How to use $indexOfArray with Go?

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework, mgo

Say I have the following data in my mongo customers collection

```
{customer:"cust1", 
 shops:[
   {name:"shop_name1", sales:200}, 
   {name:"shop_name2", sales:300}
 ]}
```

In mongo shell I can do this command and it return the index of shop_name2 in the shops array which is 1

```
db.customers.aggregate([{"$match":{customer:"cust1"}},{"$project":{"matchedIndex":{"$indexOfArray":["$shops.name","shop_name2"]}}}])
```

However in mgo

```
err := c.Pipe([]bson.M{{"$match": bson.M{"customer": "cust1"}}, {"$project": bson.M{"matchedIndex": bson.M{"$indexOfArray": []bson.M{{"$shops.name": "shop_name2"}}}}}}).One(&hehehe)
```

fails with the following message

> Unrecognized expression '$shops.name'

When I check the documentation for [$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) I note the second argument is an array. So I suspect I am specifying the array wrong but I can't find any reference on how to set this up for mgo.

Comment: It's not a "map" but just a regular list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) is simply a list of "string" so `[]string`:

```
bson.M{"$indexOfArray": []string{"$shops.name", "shop_name2"}}
```

Or in full context:

```
err := c.Pipe([]bson.M{
 {"$match": bson.M{"customer": "cust1"}},
 {"$project": bson.M{
   "matchedIndex": bson.M{"$indexOfArray": []string{"$shops.name", "shop_name2"}}
 }}
}).One(&hehehe)
```